# How to get city name from google map in ionic 2

Tags: google-maps-api-3, ionic2, angular2-template

How to obtain a city name from google map in ionic 2 If I have latitude and longitude coordinates of the area?

I searched all over the internet but I couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Geociding, as explained in this [thread](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-maps-reverse-geocoding/81713) from Ionic's forum

```
import { Geocoder, GeocoderRequest } from 'ionic-native';

let req: GeocoderRequest = { position: location }
  Geocoder.geocode(req).then((results)=>{
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find all you need about your location with this link. you can use geocode api as follow. 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY

just replace latlng by those you have and key by your API key found on google console.

> Reminder: To use the Geocoding API, you must include an API key with all API requests and you must enable billing on each of your projects

more infos here. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro

Comment: the particularity here is that the link itself is the answer, not to follow and anybody just have to replace variables by values. the second link is just for documentation.